# Ruby sending packet to a known MAC address

Tags: ruby

I like to send packet to a device with only MAC address associated to it and also connecting to my local LAN.

Is there anything in ruby / gem library that I can use to perform such task?

I want to do something like tcpreplay but in ruby instead.  Thanks!

Comment: MAC adresses aren't really supposed to be contacted without the knowledge of the IP they belong to. Can't you make sure the given MAC will always have the same IP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MACs are the addresses used on OSI layer 2, the package type you are using on this layer are e.g Ethernet frames. IP Sockets live on layer 3/4, thus if you are using an IP socket, you are sending IP packet.

So if you want to send something "to a MAC address", you need to send raw Ethernet frames which need to be understood on the other side. Given the really low level of this stuff, this is rarely what you really want to do.

Instead, you should try to get the proper IP addresses of the remote device in your local network (technically the broadcast domain) with either a broadcast/reply mechanism or with multicast (which is used e.g. by Bonjour). That way you can always use the much more supported IP layer. For that, your device needs to have an IP address of course. You can establish those with mechanisms like DHCP or address auto configuration for IPv6.

As for your question, I'm not aware of any library for Ruby to send raw Ethernet frames. But given you would need to invent a new protocol besides IP anyway (which is hard, really hard), sending the package is probably the least of your concerns.

Comment: Thank you for you replied. I am curious how tcpreplay doing the sending. all it need is which interface to replay the pcap to. Thanks again for all the help.  I will need to dig into tcpreplay code and see

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I am curious how the program 'tcpreplay' dump pcap to the eth interface.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose there are a couple of approaches.  You didn't say whether you wanted to send an IP packet of some kind, and if so you didn't say which IP protocol.  (I can tell you want to send an ethernet *frame* but ... what encapsulated protocol?)

Anyway, you can open a SOCK_RAW with Ruby, something like:

```
Socket.open(Socket::PF_INET, Socket::SOCK_RAW, Socket::IPPROTO_RAW)
```

Another approach might be to just pick a link-local IP and then establish an IP/MAC mapping in your local ARP cache with something like:

```
system "arp -s host hw_addr"
```

Then you could communicate with it using more familiar socket ops using the link-local IP address.

You need to be root for all of these things.